# Copy number of rows for n number of times using Python and write them in other file

Tags: python, csv

Hi I'm writing a simple script to copy a set of rows from a **csv** file and paste them for N number of times in other file.

I'm not able to write the result into other file.

Please find the code below:

```
import csv
for i in range(2):
    with open('C:\\Python\\CopyPaste\\result2.csv', 'r') as fp:
        data = fp.readlines()
    fp.close()

with open('C:\\Python\\CopyPaste\\mydata.csv', 'w') as mycsvfile:
    thedatawriter = csv.writer(mycsvfile)
    for row in data:
        thedatawriter.writerow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you opening & reading the input file twice? BTW, you should not use `fp.close()` when you open `fp` using `with`.

Comment: Apology I am very new to python, I saw different codes  on google and try to build this code on the basis of that. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the format of the input and output CSV files is the same, just read the input file into a string and then write it to an output file `N` times:

```
N = 3

with open('C:\\Python\\CopyPaste\\result2.csv', 'r') as infile,\
         open('C:\\Python\\CopyPaste\\mydata.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    data = fp.read()    # read entire contents of input file into data

    for i in range(N):
        outfile.write(data)
```

The above answers the question literally, however, it will replicate the header row `N` times, probably not what you want. You can do this instead:

```
import csv

N = 3

with open('C:\\Python\\CopyPaste\\result2.csv', 'r') as infile,\
         open('C:\\Python\\CopyPaste\\mydata.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(next(reader))    # reads header line and writes it to output file
    data = [row for row in reader]    # reads the rest of the input file
    for i in range(N):
        writer.writerows(data)
```

This code reads the first row from the input file as the header, and writes it *once* to the output CSV file. Then the remaining rows are read from the input file into the `data` list, and replicated `N` times in the output file.

Comment: Or just do `outfile.write(data * N)`, but I guess your version uses less RAM.

Comment: @PM2Ring: thanks for picking up the typo, fixed.  If the input file is huge it might be better to `mmap` it, but OP doesn't seem to have that problem.

Comment: I suspect that using `mmap` may be a bit too advanced for the OP at this stage...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is : read a .csv file and then write the data to another .csv file for N times?

If my recognition is right, my suggestion would be using pandas library, that's very convenient.

Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('origin.csv')
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```